# React-Native aws-amplify PubSub error

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './aws-exports'
import { PubSub } from 'aws-amplify';
import { AWSIoTProvider } from 'aws-amplify/lib/PubSub/Providers';

...

PubSub.subscribe('myTopicTest').subscribe({
   next: data => console.log('Message received', data),
   error: error => console.error(error),
   close: () => console.log('Done'),
});
```

The call to PubSub.subscribe throws :

TypeError: One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. Are you trying to assign a prototype property? We don't allow it, as this is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.

Reference :
https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/750

Does anybody has a workaround or solution for this error?

Thanks